# How to generate strings based on column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following df

```
   age
0   6
1   20
2   80
```

I want to create another column that inserts `age` in the middle of a string. I tried the following, but I did not get my desired output.

```
df['x'] = 'They are' + str(age) + 'years old.'
```

This is my desired output

```
   age            x
0   6   'They are 6 years old'
1   20  'They are 20 years old'
2   80  'They are 80 years old'
```

Comment: Try `'They are' + df["x"].astype(str) + 'years old.'`

Comment: `df['x'] = df.age.apply(lambda x: 'They are' + str(x) + 'years old.')`